# How to change content direction of Popover

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have the following component:

```
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverTrigger,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverBody,
  Portal,
  Button,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { CopyIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";

export function SelectableTooltip({
  textComponent,
  label,
}: {
  textComponent: ReactNode;
  label: string;
}) {
  return (
    <Popover trigger="hover" openDelay={100}>
      <PopoverTrigger>{textComponent}</PopoverTrigger>
      <Portal>
        <PopoverContent>
          <PopoverBody>{label}</PopoverBody>
          <Button
            rightIcon={<CopyIcon />}
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(label)}
          />
        </PopoverContent>
      </Portal>
    </Popover>
  );
}
```

It renders like this:

[image: layout 2]

Instead of the button being underneath the text, I want it to be to the right of the text.

Some things I've tried:

```
        <PopoverContent>
          <PopoverBody>
            {label}
            <Button
              rightIcon={<CopyIcon />}
              size="sm"
              onClick={() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(label)}
            />
          </PopoverBody>
        </PopoverContent>
```

I get this:

[image]

This is not right, I want it to be its own section, not laid out inline with the text. So, similar to how the original layout looks, but on the right rather than on the bottom.

```
        <PopoverContent flexDirection="row">
          <PopoverBody>{label}</PopoverBody>
          <Button
            rightIcon={<CopyIcon />}
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(label)}
          />
        </PopoverContent>
```

I get this:

[image]

The way this overflows outside the box is not what I'm looking for either.

How do I get the icon to appear to the right properly?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

do you mean like this?

```
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverTrigger,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverBody,
  Portal,
  Button, Heading
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { CopyIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Popover trigger="hover" openDelay={100}>
      <PopoverTrigger>
        <Heading>test
        </Heading>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <Portal>
        <PopoverContent>
          <PopoverBody>
                <Heading>test
        </Heading>
          </PopoverBody>
          <Button
            width="min-content"
            p='4'
            ml='auto'
            rightIcon={<CopyIcon ml='auto' />}
            size="sm"
          />
        </PopoverContent>
      </Portal>
    </Popover>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hmmm doesn't seem to work, the icon appears in the bottom right corner.